# Store every value in a sequence except some values

Tags: r

If I do the following to a string of letters:

```
x <- 'broke'
y <- nchar(x)
z <- sequence(y)
```

How do I store every value of the `z` that isn't the first, last, or middle values of the sequence.

In this example if `z` is `1 2 3 4 5` then the desired output would be `2 4`

in the case of `1 2 3 4` nothing would be stored however, In the case of say `1 2 3 4 5 6` , `2` and `5` would be stored and so on

Comment: What happens if you have an even number of elements, ie `1 2 3 4`?

Comment: in the case of `1 2 3 4` nothing would be stored however, In the case of say `1 2 3 4 5 6` , `2` and `5` would be stored and so on. Let me add this to the question, thanks.

Comment: @Gimme next time be more specific, I though that the length of your object  was always 5.

Comment: OP when you say 'and so on', is the capture for 1 to 8, `2 3 6 7`?

Comment: @plafort yes that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (length(z) %% 2) {
    z[-c(1, ceiling(length(z)/2), length(z))]
} else
    z[-c(1, c(1,0) + floor(length(z)/2), length(z))]
```

Comment: this works good for the example I have provided, however I edited the question, sorry!